# Rails get index of "each" loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have this loop:

```
<% @images.each do |page| %>

<% end %>
```

How would I get the index of "page" inside of the loop?

Comment: For the info of others looking at this, all the answers supplied are applicable to Ruby in general, not specific to Rails functionality.

Comment: Just loop through each_with_index and you are good to go!

Answer (score 404, accepted):

```
<% @images.each_with_index do |page, index| %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Had to use the each_with_index method as the other answers suggest.

Answer (score 52):

The two answers are good.
And I also suggest you a similar method:

```
<% @images.each.with_index do |page, index| %>
<% end %>
```

You might not see the difference between this and the accepted answer. Let me direct your eyes to these method calls: `.each.with_index` see how it's `.each` and then `.with_index`.

Comment: This method newer and allows you to offset the index (say you wanted to start the loop on item 1 instead of 0 or something like that)

Comment: It took me a while to realise this code wasn't identical to the accepted answer!

Answer (score 16):

Try [each_with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Enumerable.html#M001172).